# Cron Syntax, MAC OS X

Tags: python, cron

#### Quick Summary of Issue

I would to run a python script every minute of everyday.  I would like cron to run the following 2 commands (in this order) every minute:

```
cd ~/desktop/WebProgramming
python MyPythonScript.py
```

Is it possible for cron to run 2 commands?

#### More Detailed Explanation

I am having difficulty running a python script in the cron scheduler for mac.  Essentially, I would like to run the script every minute, here is my Cron syntax:

```
* * * * * python ~/desktop/WebProgramming/MyPythonFile.py
```

MyPythonFile uses severals of the files in the WebProgrammingFolder--when I first navigate to the directory (`cd ~/desktop/WebProgramming/`) and manually run the script, the program runs fine.  However, I get an error when I try to run it on cron, saying that "No File is In the Directory" referring to the code within MyPythonFile that refers to the other files in the folder.  Therefore, I would like cron to navigate to this directory, and then execute the command the run the file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proper fix would be to make `MyPythonFile.py` look in the appropriate directory for its files.

If you don't want to do that (...), then:

```
* * * * * cd ~/desktop/WebProgramming ; python MyPythonScript.py
```

Answer (score 1):

`... (cd ~/desktop/WebProgramming/ && python ...)`

Answer (score 0):

Try and specify absolute paths to scripts when using cron

Comment: That alone won't help if the script itself uses relative paths.